# FFT of a 2d array with NAN

Tags: 2d, fft, nan

I'm trying to apply FFT on a 2D array with NAN. I don't want to replace the NAN values with anything. Is there a way to apply FFT and ignore the NAN values?

```
arr=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, NAN, 6], [1, 2, NAN]])
f=np.fft.fft2(arr)
```

Comment: How would you expect an FFT that  "ignores NAN" to behave? As if those were zeros? Also, any reason why you don't want to replace the NAN values? Do you simply want to preserve your source, or do you have memory constraints that would make a temporary copy where NAN are replaced impractical?

Answer (score 0):

No.  An FFT will propagate any unknown input to every output.  This because in a transform such as a DFT, every output value directly depends on every input value, and thus can not be computed without known values for every input.

Or, an alternate answer is Yes: If any input to an FFT is an NaN, just output the FFT result as an appropriately sized array completely filled with NaNs.